# How do I get a lookup table in Microsoft Access 2007 to update data in both the original table and the current table it's being updated in?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to set up a table (Table A) that has multiple fields from 3 different Tables/Queries (Tables B,C, Query D) through the lookup wizard. Table A gets 8 fields from Table B. Table A gets 1 field from Table C. Table A gets 1 field from Query D. I also have 1 extra Yes/No field that was made in Table A.

If I update or change any of the data in Tables B, C or, Query D then Table A will see all of the information from those fields. This is how I want it to work, but the issue is the next part.

If I update data in Table A or add extra data that isn't in Tables B, C, or Query D the data doesn't get added to the original Tables/Query. I need it so that when I add data into Table A, the data will also be added into Tables B, C, and Query D.

**Overall question:** 
How do I make it so that the fields in Table A synchronize with the fields in Tables B, C, and Query D regardless of which table/query the data is changed in?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the terminology when you say that you want new or updated information "added into ... Query D". Select Queries are dynamic views of data from one or more Tables. Those queries do not store information themselves, they merely display information that is stored in the underlying Tables.

> How do I make it so that the fields in Table A synchronize with the fields in Tables B, C, and Query D regardless of which table/query the data is changed in?

The short answer is: You don't.

You've already got the information in Tables B and C, and (I presume) in the underlying table(s) of Query D, so you should **not** store that information (again) in Table A. Doing that would be what is called *denormalizing* the data, and should be avoided where possible.

Instead, you should *only* store information in Table A if it is not available anywhere else (e.g., the Yes/No field you mentioned in your question). Then, if you want something that pulls in the information from the other tables you should create a **Query_A** that brings it all together.